# Graph network usage per IP on Linux router

Tags: ubuntu, router, display, bandwidth

I'm going to be setting up an Ubuntu server as a router. There are dual gigabit NICs on the motherboard and I'll also use a wifi card as an AP.

The question is, once I have this running, can I monitor network bandwidth usage per client (both wired and wireless)?